# How To Query Contacts having valid email address in Constructor

Tags: apex

Tried by using EmailRegex
but didn't get the expected output

```
public String emailRegex = '([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@(((\\[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3}))';


for(contact c : [SELECT Id,name,email FROM Contact
                 where (Email<>'' AND Email = 'emailRegex') )
```

Comment: By definition, values in Contact.Email in the database are valid email addresses

Answer (score 3):

SOQL doesn't perform regex matching. You will have to query all relevant contacts and post-filter them against the regex [using apex patterns and matchers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_using.htm).

You can apply some very primitive restrictions directly in the SOQL using LIKE:

```
SELECT ... WHERE (Email LIKE '%@%')
```

for example, to exclude all cases where there is no "@" in the email address.

That said, the Email property on Contact is an email address type field so should already apply validation and only allow "valid" email addresses to be assigned.

Answer (score 1):

The email field on contact is already validated by Salesforce, so you don't have to. Also, you can't use regex in SOQL queries. You could validate the email adres after the query with regex, but not before. (You could consider the [LIKE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm) operator, but that is rather limited compared to regex.)

Answer (score 0):

Acheived by writing if condition

```
if(Pattern.matches('([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@(((\\[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3}))', c.Email))
```